# Plugin not taking acount a newly created field in a called Algorithm

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, fields-attributes

I'm trying to write a qgis plugin and I'm having trouble when updating fields.

So here's the code:

```
# Create an Id column to be used as reference to the areas feature after the union
idnumber = 0
LYR_VECTORAREA.dataProvider().addAttributes([QgsField("id_temp", QVariant.Int)])
for feature in LYR_VECTORAREA.getFeatures():
     LYR_VECTORAREA.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues({ feature.id() : {fieldcounter: idnumber}})
     idnumber += 1
LYR_VECTORAREA.updateFields()
# Checking if the field has been created
for field in LYR_VECTORAREA.pendingFields():
     print field.name()

# Run the Union geoprocessing
processing.runalg("saga:union",LYR_VECTORAREA,LYR_VECTORDISTRIBUTION,False,VECTOROUTPUT)
```

The union processing doesn't take into account the newly added field. Even if the printed fields assess that the field has been created at this stage of the script (so, before processing the union), the new field never gets through to the output of the union.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, after investigating on how the algorithm were getting the inputs parameters, I found out that the problem was coming from the module 'dataobjects', when the algorithm is loading the input shapefiles, the method 'getObjectFromUri' is called and this method loads the shapefiles if they're not existing on the canvas and get the ones on the canvas if these are loaded **even if the input parameter is the source path** (not a vector layer object). So, if the layer we added a field to isn't refresh on the canvas, the algorithm isn't going to take the updated version of it. The solution of that is to unload the layers from the canvas or to add the following line:

```
self.iface.mapCanvas().refreshAllLayers()
```

after creating the new field but before executing the algorithm.

This is my bad though since this was noticed in the qgis cookbook...